# How do I fix over limit y axis value in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

**Hello Everyone!**

I am using `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` to prevent unhoverable tiny values by displaying the value above his bar, but when one of them has the highest value the datalabels exceed the limit of the chart container

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also, you can use `suggestedMax` option and I think it's better than giving a padding

```
const options = {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      color: '#374774',
      font: { family: 'MyriadSemiBold', size: 14 },
      align: 'end',
      anchor: 'end',
      formatter: (value) => {
        if (value > 0) {
          return localizeNumber(value)
        }

        return ''
      },
    },
    legend: { display: false },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: { lineWidth: 0 },
      ticks: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    y: {
      // Highest value in your datasets
      suggestedMax: highestValue > 0 ? highestValue + 1e5 : 10,
      grid: { color: '#DFDFDF' },
      ticks: {
        callback: (value) => {
          return abbreviateNumber(value)
        },
        font: { family: 'MyriadRegular', size: 14 },
        color: '#374774',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to [add padding](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html) to the top of your chart (simple sample below). You may also play around with the datalabel plugin's [clamping](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#clamping) options to adjust the position of the label when it's outside the chart.

```js
const layoutOptions =  {
    padding: {
        top: 30  // Add 30 pixels of padding to top of chart.
    }
};

const data = {
    labels: ['Large', 'Small'],
    datasets: [{ data: [100, 2] }]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        layout: layoutOptions,
        scales: { y: { beginAtZero: true, max: 100 } },
        plugins: {
            legend: { display: false },
            datalabels: { anchor: 'end', align: 'top' }
        }
    },
};

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
```

```css
#myChart {
    max-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<script>Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);</script>
```