# Chart js padding isn't working for data labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**I tried adding padding above my graphs, but it did not work**.  I went to the options.layout.padding section of the graph.  The data labels just sit on top of the bar and look really bad.  **So either a way to add padding above graph, or some way to fix the labels being on top of the bars would help**.  I am using the Chart js data labels plugin.

Javascript Code:

```js
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <canvas id="myChart" class="bar-chart"></canvas>
            <script>
            Chart.register(ChartDataLabels); /* Register chart for data label plugin */
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Lithium Battery', 'Other Mfg', 'Delivery', 'Tailpipe', 'Fuel Cycle', 'Disposal', 'Total'],
                    value_labels: [ /* labels above the chart */
                        {{data['icev_lit_bat']}}, 
                        ... (Ommited for space)
                    ],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'ICEV CAR (MTCO2e/Year)',
                        data: [  /* errors are normal, fixes when server runs the code*/
                            [0, {{data['y1_icev']}}],
                            [{{data['y1_icev']}}, ... ommited for space
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderSkipped: false
                    }]
                },
                options: { /* Chart settings */
                    scales: {
                        y:{
                            ticks:{
                                font:{
                                    size: 20
                                },
                                stepSize:0.5
                            },
                            max: 7,
                            min: 0,
                            stepSize: 1
                        },
                        x:{
                            ticks:{
                                font:{
                                    size: 18
                                },
                            },
                        }    
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            top: 30,
                            bottom: 0
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: false,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            labels: {
                                font: {
                                    size: 20
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        datalabels: {
                            color: '#000',
                            anchor: 'end',
                            formatter: function(value, context) { /* sets custom labels */
                                return context.chart.data.value_labels[context.dataIndex];
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            });
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix over limit y axis value in ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635407/how-do-i-fix-over-limit-y-axis-value-in-chartjs)

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: Care to add why it didn't work for you because as you can see in the duplicate answer it works fine, so without any more info why this isn't working for you answering this question is almost impossible

Comment: I'm not sure why the padding didn't work for my chart, but it just made no changes to the bars for some reason.  I figured out another solution though, so it worked out.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to use align: 'top'

```js
plugins: {
    legend: {
        labels: {
            font: {
                size: 20
            }
        }
    },
    datalabels: {
        color: '#000',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        formatter: function(value, context) { /* sets custom labels */
            return context.chart.data.value_labels[context.dataIndex];
        }
    }
},
```